# Webpack css-loader is not importing CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have Server rendered my `create-react-app` by reading [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering).

And now, I cannot import CSS files in `.js` files!

Tried using `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, `mini-css-extract-plugin`, tried tweaking webpack configuration, but nothing helped.

NO StackOverflow answer helped. So this question.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev:build-server": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=development -w",
    "dev:start": "nodemon ./server-build/index.js",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build dev:*",
    "start": "serve --single ./build",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "now-build": "react-scripts build && mv build dist",
    "deploy": "npm run build && now ./build -A ../now.json --public --name=kumarabhirup"
  },
  ...
}
```

This is `webpack.server.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/index.js',

  target: 'node',

  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('server-build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'] NOT WORKED
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') // NOT WORKING
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({...process.env}),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css') // TRIED THIS TOO
    // new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ TRIED THIS
    //   filename: 'style.css',
    // })
  ]
};
```

Error it throws at me when I, `import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css'`,

```
/Users/iqubex/Sites/kumarabhirup/kumarabhirup/node_modules/react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css:7
.CircularProgressbar {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

All that I expect is the working of imported CSS files. Please help

Comment: `module: {loaders: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},{test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']}]}`, can you try this and make the plugins array in webpack to empty.

Comment: this too, isnt working ☹️

Comment: Do you implort css from the dist directory? The output is not set to `dist` directory but is that safe? I mean isn't there any other program to write in that folder? Can you show me your project structure? (Directories)

Comment: I created another project, which was custom and with no CRA... this time it worked... it must be due to the file structure. anyways, thanks for the help. Your answer worked when I did all from scratch. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@gopigorantala is right.

Change the loader to one of these, it should work:

```
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
```

or

```
use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
```

You probably won't need to use ExtractTextPlugin. Just use MiniCssExtractPlugin. It'll work.

The `style-loader` loads the styles into DOM with `<style>` at runtime, and `MiniCssExtractPlugin` extract them to a separate file. So you don't need to use both of them.

Comment: Yet facing problems

Comment: @Slach upload your project (or a sample) in git, and I will check it

Comment: @AliDoustkani https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin/issues/162